In a magnetic field, does the force act on the midpoint of the current carrying wire?


Here, it says that the force acts on the middle points of the wires, but why?
What do they mean by when they are saying that the forces 1 and 3 are acting on the same line of action? How does that affect torque?



Believe it may just be a convenient approximation since the force is actually distributed along the entire length of the wire, which would be harder to represent in an FBD.
When they say forces F1 and F3 have the same line of action, they mean that these two forces act along the same axis. This is evident from the diagram, where F1 and F3 are parallel and opposite in direction (Fleming's LHR, B is out of the page). Forces acting along the same line cannot produce a net rotational effect because torque arises from forces having perpendicular moment arms relative to the axis of rotation.


The key concept and word  here is equipollent.  Two systems of forces are "equipollent" if they have the same total force and same moments about any point. The magentic force taken to act at the midpoint of the sides is equipolent  to the actual forces.  This is just as gravity that acts on a whole body can be conveniently taken to act at the center of mass.
